# how to package egui

Tags: rust, egui, eframe

How to package an egui project into a single exe to run on someone else's windows computer
Here is the cargo.toml file

```ini
[package]
name = "autodark-egui-rr-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[profile.release]
opt-level = "z"  # 最大优化级别
panic = "abort"  # 在panic时中止程序

[dependencies]
eframe ="0.23.0"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
chrono = "0.4.31"
winreg="0.51.0"
```

I've tried `cargo build --release` and it doesn't work.
Is it because it's not statically compiled? I'm new to application development and don't know much about this, sorry!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: "_It doesn't work_" → what doesn't work?